# Mysql get sum(B.column) of TABLE B to the sum of 5, add to every new row of TABLE A

Tags: mysql

I want to sum up values from **Table B Bonus.value** where **redeemed=0** up to the sum of 5, such that when it sums up to 5 it gets added to the result table from **TABLE A purchase** where **Redeemed=0** related by **customer_id** as shown in the image below

At the moment I have this, but returns total sum for each record:

```
select *,(select Sum(b.value) from bonus b WHERE b.Bonus_type='purchase' AND 
b.Customer_id=1 AND b.redeemed=0) AS 'pbonus', (select Sum(b.value) from bonus b WHERE 
b.Bonus_type='referral' AND b.Customer_id=1 AND b.redeemed=0) AS 'rbonus' FROM purchase p 
where p.Customer_id = 1 AND p.redeemed = 0;
```

[image: (Purchase - Table A, Bonus -Table B and Result Table]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't really follow the example. Your description does not mention the redeemed fields, but in your query they are used. I do not understand how the purchase and bonus tables are related. I do not understand how you can differentiate between records in the purchase table. There is no unique column or combination of columns.

Comment: @Shadow each customer gets a bonus for every purchase or referral they make but can't redeem until it sums up to 5 for each bonus type. The result table (orange table) shows the bonus overview for Customer with id 1

Comment: You have not answered half of my questions.

Comment: Nope. Still cannot distinguish between the purchases.

Comment: I'm not sure if your logic is correct at all. If you want to associate bonuses with purchases, then you should have a separate purchase id field in the bonus table.

Comment: @Shadow for every purchase each customer make, they get a bonus (purchase) as shown on the bonus table. There is no unique column. Ok if, I have that, how can my query be tweaked to achieve that result?

Comment: Nope because still there is nothing to associate a bonus with a purchase. You have to store the association. Your application logic seems flawed.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use "group by customer_id" when you need to sum up for the same customer id